# Discrete Math Textbook

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics

For my discrete math class, we are using the textbook Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, by Rosen. I really like the exercises given at the end of chapters, they are quite challenging at times, but I don't find the actual treatise on concepts very helpful, nor do I find the example problems at all comparable to the exercises. I was wondering if anyone knew of a good introductory discrete textbook that covered the same topics as Rosen's textbook.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at Edward Scheinerman, *Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction*, and Susanna Epp, *Discrete Mathematics with Applications*. I prefer Scheinerman’s book, but it’s aimed a bit more at math majors and less at computer science majors than Rosen’s and may not match up as well as you’d like. Epp’s book is closer in spirit to Rosen’s, I’d say. Both books spend more time than most on helping the student *write* proofs. Of the two, I’d say that Epp does just a bit more hand-holding.

Comment: Actually, that is another thing I forgot mention when enumerating the things that I dislike about Rosen's book: a lot of the example problems are involve knowledge of computer science, of which I have known. So, if you are saying that Scheinerman's book is better for math major's, I'd probably enjoy it.

Answer (score 3):

Another very thorough textbook is *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* by Susanna Epp.  David Hunter's *Essentials of Discrete Mathematics* is another favorite.

In the course I'm currently teaching, though, we're using Richard Hammack's *Book of Proof*.  It is narrower in scope, but seems to have good exposition for what is covered.  It also has the advantage of being free: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/